# How does splice work exactly in angularjs/javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects:-

```
$scope.obj=[{"id":1,"content_type_name":"collections"},{"id":2,"content_type_name":"collections"},{"id":3,"content_type_name":"random"}];
```

Now when i try running my loop of angularForEach only the first collection entry(i.e. one with id=1 is getting removed but the one with id=2 stays). Ideally expected output should only be an object with id=3. Following is the code:-

```
angular.forEach($scope.obj, function(content, index){
       if(content.content_type_name == "collections"){
           $scope.obj.splice(index,1);
       }
});
```

However when I run this, it works perfectly fine:-

```
for(var i=$scope.obj.length-1;i>=0;--i){
        if($scope.obj[i].content_type_name == "collections"){
            $scope.obj.splice(i,1);
        }
  }
```

I am not getting a clear picture of why splice is not working.

Some help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the angular forEach loop starts at the beginning of the array, while your second example with the for loop starts at the end and goes back through.  Since you're removing an element when 'collections' is found as the content_type_name, that will shift the index of every other item in the array down 1.

In the Angular forEach loop, it starts on index 0, removes it, then moves on to index 1, which is now the final element in the array since one was just removed.  Basically it's skipping over the second element.

Your second example, using the for loop, doesn't have this problem since it's moving backwards through the array.  So it checks index 2, doesn't do anything, checks index 1, removes it, and moves on to index 0, which it also removes.  Hope I worded this well enough...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a filter

```
$scope.obj = $scope.obj.filter(function(e){
   return e.content_type_name == "collections"
});
```

Then you don't have to remove every single element